# Sporadic IndexOutOfBoundsException when Andengine application start

Tags: java, android, mobile, andengine

I've an Android application using AndEngine and I get this sporadic error when application start. This error is logged sometimes but only when application start. Does anyone have this same error?

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 4, size is 4
        at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
        at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
        at org.andengine.entity.Entity.onManagedDraw(Entity.java:1382)
        at org.andengine.entity.scene.Scene.onManagedDraw(Scene.java:260)
        at org.andengine.entity.Entity.onDraw(Entity.java:1160)
        at org.andengine.engine.Engine.onDrawScene(Engine.java:627)
        at org.andengine.engine.Engine.onDrawFrame(Engine.java:617)
        at org.andengine.opengl.view.EngineRenderer.onDrawFrame(EngineRenderer.java:105)
        at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1522)
        at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1249)
```

Comment: What should happen on application start? Do you have splash screen? Menu scene?

Comment: Yes, I've a splash screen during load global resources.

Comment: I'm not sure but this may happen when you dispose entities unproperly... do you do anything like that?